# Mac NPM Wrong Version

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to get my project started but I got this error.
[Error from Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seLhF.png)

The environment requires npm 6.x or lower. I checked with Terminal and it does satisfy the required version.
[my npm version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT1Ps.png)

I had once installed node v16 using the official installer before but soon I uninstalled it by following the steps I googled (like sudo rm all node-related stuff).

What I had done includes the following:

- Clear Cache, Remove package-lock.json, Remove node_modules, and reinstall - not working
- rm all the node-related files and reinstall node (v14) - not working
- use nvm to run - not working

Here is the debug log I got from npm:

```json
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.16
3 info using node@v12.22.12
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~prestart: sentry_fe@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~start: sentry_fe@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~start: PATH: /Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/Documents/WORK/governance-sentry-fe/node_modules/.bin:/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
9 verbose lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/Documents/WORK/governance-sentry-fe
10 silly lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'eden start' ]
11 silly lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle sentry_fe@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: sentry_fe@1.0.0 start: `eden start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid sentry_fe@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/Documents/WORK/governance-sentry-fe
16 verbose Darwin 21.3.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node" "/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/npm" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v12.22.12
19 verbose npm  v6.14.16
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error sentry_fe@1.0.0 start: `eden start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the sentry_fe@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Would any one imply other methods that I can use? Any responses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I'll try my best to answer.</sub>

You can reinstall the latest version of Node.js from the [official website](https://nodejs.org/) (it should remove the old version).

This should also install npm at version 8.

---

To downgrade npm, you need to run the following command.

```
$ npm install -g npm@6.14.16
```

This should leave Node.js at the highest version, and npm at your desired version.

Answer (score 0):

install n;

```
npm install -g n
```

or without node on mac;

```
brew install n
```

after installation execute;

```
n 16.15.1
```

if you want other versions;

```
n <version>
```

or you can install last via;

```
n latest
```

i advise for new developers;

```
n lts
```

also you can switch installed versions via

```
n
```

[For more info...](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)